# How to do a simple image explode in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need an image explode effect in jQuery. On click the image should explode, which one is simple and gave more particles...

ie,  on clicking an image it should explode into particles...

What is the simplest one possible?

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple demo follow this one.

```
<html>
       <head>
          <title>The jQuery Example</title>
          <script type = "text/javascript" 
             src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
          </script>
          <script type = "text/javascript" 
             src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js">
          </script>
          <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#hide").click(function(){
                   $(".target").hide( "explode", {pieces: 16 }, 2000 );
                });
                $("#show").click(function(){
                   $(".target").show( "explode", {pieces: 16}, 2000 );
                }); 
             });
          </script>
          <style>
             p {background-color:#bca; width:200px; border:1px solid green;}
             div{width:100px; height:100px; background:red;}
          </style>
       </head>

       <body>
          <p>Click on any of the buttons</p>    
          <button id = "hide"> Hide </button>
          <button id = "show"> Show</button> 
        <div class = "target">
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: very simple and handy...great

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<img src="imagePath" id="toggle" />

<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "explode" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: whwn i put an image in src and tested it it didnt worked...

Comment: please show in a snippet